# Nest.js React.js SSL certificate with let's encrypt pm2

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, ssl-certificate, pm2, lets-encrypt

I built and app using nest.js and react.js, now I am running my apps in production on a windows server using pm2 but, I want to turn it to https how can I do it when I'm running them with pm2.

I tried using win-acme but, the app should run on IIS.
I tried running my app using IIS, I got so many errors so I got back to pm2.